# How to write file to every directory that is read?

Tags: node.js, image, file, npm

I have the following folder structure below and wanted to create a file in each directory indicating which files were read. After the file is created, I want to use that file as a conditional to determine if I should skip or read from that directory.

**Question(s)**

1. How can I write a file to the directory with all the files read?
2. How can I use that file in conditional logic to read or skip that file directory?

**Current Folder Structure (before running nodejs)**

- sub folder 1
  -- file 1
  -- file 2
  -- file 3
- sub folder 2
  -- file 3
  -- file 4
- sub folder 3
  -- file 5
  -- file 6

**Desired Output (after running nodejs file)**

- sub folder 1
  -- file 1
  -- file 2
  -- file 3
  -- files-read.txt
- sub folder 2
  -- file 3
  -- file 4
  -- files-read.txt
- sub folder 3
  -- file 5
  -- file 6
  -- files-read.txt

**What I have tried but got stuck**

```
const fs = require('fs');
var targetDirectory = '../my/path/to/target';
var filesRead = [];

fs.readdir(targetDirectory, function (err, files) {

  if(err) return console.log('error: ' + err);

  files.forEach(function(file) {
   // HELP - how do i not read if files-read.txt already exists in directory?
   filesRead.push(file);
  });

});

var fileName = 'files-read.txt';

fs.writeFile(fileName, filesRead, function (err) {
  if(err) return console.log('error: ' + err);
  /// help -- how do i only write if files-read.text doesn't exist?
  console.log('finished writing');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cycle through the sub folders.
In your case it would look like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
var targetDirectory = __dirname + '/target';
var filesRead = [];
var fileName = 'files-read.txt';

const { readdirSync } = fs;

const getDirectories = (source) =>
  readdirSync(source, { withFileTypes: true })
    .filter((dirent) => dirent.isDirectory())
    .map((dirent) => dirent.name);

const directories = getDirectories(targetDirectory);

directories
  .map((dir) =>
    fs.readdir(targetDirectory + '/' + dir, function (err, files) {
      if (err) return console.log('error: ' + err);
      if(files.includes(fileName)) {
        // Check to see if the file already exists
        return null
      }
      fs.writeFile(fileName, filesRead, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log('error: ' + err);
        console.log(files); // or do what ever you want here
        console.log('finished writing');
      });
    })
  );
```

Comment: I am getting error message ` dirent.isDirectory()`, what do i need to include or how do i resolve this?

Comment: Probably a node version issue, can you upgrade it?

Comment: all packages have the latest version. does `dirent.isDirectory()` require me to include some package? my node version is `v17.5.0` btw